# How to extract XML Value in Oracle Database

Tags: sql, xml, oracle

I have a table in an Oracle 12c Database that contains a XML Type Column and i need to extract a value from this Column.
Here an example of this Column's content:

```html
<AbcMsg xmlns="http://example.org/SCL/CommonTypes">
  <Msg>
    <Pmnt>
      <swif:SWIFT MT="202" xmlns:swif="urn:abc/scl/SWIFT" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
        <swif:Header>
          <swif:Input_Output_Identifier>O</swif:Input_Output_Identifier>
          <swif:Sender_BIC>XXXXXXXXXXX</swif:Sender_BIC>
          <swif:Receiver_BIC>XXXXXXXXXXX</swif:Receiver_BIC>
          <swif:Message_Priority>NORM</swif:Message_Priority>
          <swif:User_Header>
            <swif:Message_User_Reference>XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX</swif:Message_User_Reference>
          </swif:User_Header>
          <swif:Original_Swift>
            <swif:Message>DATA TO BE EXTRACTED</swif:Message>
          </swif:Original_Swift>
          <swif:Create_Date_Time>2016-07-28T15:45:00</swif:Create_Date_Time>
          <swif:Msg_ID>POFu7yCXHoN</swif:Msg_ID>
          <swif:Sequence_Number>248600</swif:Sequence_Number>
          <swif:Session_Number>6184</swif:Session_Number>
        </swif:Header>
        <swif:Data xsi:type="swif:Data_202">
          <swif:F20>
            <swif:Sender_s_Reference>POFu7yCXHoN</swif:Sender_s_Reference>
          </swif:F20>
          <swif:F21>
            <swif:Related_Reference>XXXXXXXXXXX</swif:Related_Reference>
          </swif:F21>
          <swif:F32A>
            <swif:Currency>USD</swif:Currency>
            <swif:Amount>156020000</swif:Amount>
            <swif:Date>2016-07-28</swif:Date>
          </swif:F32A>
          <swif:Cdrt_F58a_F59a>
            <swif:Account>174208531</swif:Account>
            <swif:Identifier_Code>XXXXXXXXX</swif:Identifier_Code>
          </swif:Cdrt_F58a_F59a>
        </swif:Data>
      </swif:SWIFT>
    </Pmnt>
    <Extn/>
  </Msg>
</AbcMsg>
```

I need to retrieve the Value of `<swif:Original_Swift>`. I've tried the function EXTRACT(xml_column, '/AbcMsg/Msg/Pmnt') but it keeps returning null.

Any clue on how to do that???

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: I solved it with a different approach, using other function. But it up to you to keep it as duplicate.

Answer (score 1):

Try xmltable or xmlquery. You have to declare defult and swif namesapce;

```
 select * from xmltable(XMLNAMESPACES('urn:abc/scl/SWIFT' as "swif",  default 'http://example.org/SCL/CommonTypes') , '/AbcMsg/Msg/Pmnt/swif:SWIFT/swif:Header/swif:Original_Swift'  passing xmltype(your_xml_here));
```

Comment: I was able to perform what I wanted using the EXTRACTVALUE function:

`EXTRACTVALUE(xml_column, '//b:Header/b:Original_Swift',  'xmlns:b="urn:abc/scl/SWIFT"') AS "Extracted"`

Comment: Yes it is possible. But oracle marks `extractvalue` as deprecated and it recommended to use `xmltable` and `xmlquery`. [check note](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e41084/functions061.htm#SQLRF06173)

Comment: Didn't know about that. Thanks so much for the info!